# Jupyter Notebookのターミナルで半角の文字が入力できません。

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

MacOS High Sierra 10.13.4を使用しています。
Jupyter Notebook内でターミナルを使用する際に、なぜか全角での入力しか反応せず困っています。
何か解決策があれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

日本語入力の半角モードだとダメでABCならうまくいきました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに「ABC」は「システム環境設定」/「キーボード」/「入力ソース」の画面の「＋」ボタンから追加できます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

自分も同じ症状がでましたが、Safariではなく別のブラウザのVivaldiから開くと問題が起こりませんでした。MacOS Sierra 10.12.6です。

Answer (score 0):

同じ症状で困っていますが, とりあえず他のテキストアプリで半角入力してからコピペすれば動きますよ. とりあえず応急処置はコレで.

Answer (score 0):

CapsLockキーが押されていませんか？

Answer (score 0):

僕も同じ現象になります。
jupytyer notebookではセルからもコマンドが実行できるので、
セルで!pip installを使うと良いと思います。